# How do I store the lambda value with tukeyTransform in R?

Tags: r, tukey

I need to transform my data to a normal distribution and I'm using the transformTukey function from the rcompanion library. The issue I'm having is when I transform the data back to the original scale I have to manually input the lambda value. Is there a way to store the lambda value when I run the transformTukey function?

```
df$CTR_TRANSFORMED <- transformTukey(df$CTR)

    lambda      W Shapiro.p.value
420  0.475 0.9981          0.6588

if (lambda >  0){TRANS = x ^ lambda} 
if (lambda == 0){TRANS = log(x)} 
if (lambda <  0){TRANS = -1 * x ^ lambda} 


sqldf("select power(CTR_TRANSFORMED,(1/0.475)) as CTR_DETRANSFORMED
       from df")
```

How do I store the 0.475 lambda as its own object so I can reference it dynamically later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `transformTukey` with the argument `returnLambda = TRUE` it will return the lambda value and nothing else. So if you want to store the lambda value in the varible `x` you can run

```
x <- transformTukey(df$CTR, returnLambda = TRUE)
```

This is explained in the function's documentation which can be accessed by running `?transformTukey`

> ```
> returnLambda  
> If TRUE, returns only the lambda value, not the vector of transformed values.
> ```

Comment: I get the following error when I run that command:        Error in transformTukey(df$CTR, returnLambda = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (returnLambda = TRUE)

Comment: Are you using the `transformTukey` function from `rcompanion` ? You can check the namespace by running `transformTukey` with no parenthesis and looking at the bottom of the results. That argument is shown in the [function's documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rcompanion/versions/2.2.1/topics/transformTukey) so you should not be getting an "unused argument" error.

Comment: A more direct way of checking whether that is one of the arguments in your function is to run `formals(transformTukey)`

Comment: I tried both of those options and didn't see ```returnLambda``` as an argument. Turns out I was still on version ```rcompanion_2.0.0``` so once I updated the package I was able to use the ```returnLambda = TRUE``` argument. Thanks